# docker logs を tail -f したい

Tags: docker

`docker run -d` で daemon として run した container に対して、その実行過程を観察したいと思いました。 tail -f のように、端末をバインドして変更があればそれが追記されていくようなことができたらいいなと思いました。しかし、 docker logs は基本的にすぐさまその実行が終了してしまいます。

## 質問

- docker logs の出力を、`tail -f` のように継続的に観測したいです。これはどうやったら実現できますか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker logs`の`-f`オプション(「follow log output」)ではいかがでしょうか?

Comment: まんまですね、、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

`docker logs -f --tail=100 <container-name>`
で最後の指定した行数からログを表示し続けられます。